# how to map my app to my domain in AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am very new to AWS.

I have a java app which runs in AWS instance and I am able to run that using following `myIp:8080/myApp`

Also I have my domain (mydomain.com) registered with S3bucket, Now this domain shows the index page provided by AWS.

I am looking for show my java app as a domain home page. if I enter mydomain.com in browser I want to access the java app.

Previously in  other hosts, I can put `.htaccess` file to rewrite urls. But in AWS I cant do that.

How do I rewrite in AWS to my app for my domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can point the A record to the instance ip, then on the instance set up apache to act as a proxy and reroute traffic on port 80 to 8080, or change the service so it runs on port 80.

Or point the domain to an elastic load balancer and have the load balancer point to port 8080 on the instance.

Comment: @JQuery We don't do tutorials here. MaartenS gave you good advice that tells you what needs to happen to resolve your problem. Now it's up to you, the professional systems administrator, to figure out how to do it. There are quite literally thousands of guides online that can help you out.